# Creating Rest API in Deno

Tags: javascript, rest, deno

I am working on creating REST API in Deno but could not get a handful resources. Could someone help me to get started with?
Something similar to express router :

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {

});

router.post('/savedata', function (req, res) {

});
```

Comment: Try this: https://dev.to/kryz/write-a-small-api-using-deno-1cl0 using oak middleware

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Awesome Deno](https://github.com/denolib/awesome-deno) is a list of existing tools built to work on Deno, and the list is actively maintained by Deno contributors. You might be able to find useful frameworks there.

[Oak](https://github.com/oakserver/oak) and [ABC](https://github.com/zhmushan/abc) are two I know from the list that are actively maintained. You might also find other frameworks that fits your need better.

Answer (score 1):

[Oak](https://github.com/oakserver/oak) Framework is used mainly for API purposes. You can follow [this](https://codehexz.com/blog/getting-started-with-deno/) awesome step-by-step guide to develop a simple REST API in deno using Deno, Typescript and Oak.

https://codehexz.com/blog/getting-started-with-deno/

Answer (score 1):

If you intend using the **OAK Framework**, this could be an approach.

```
import { Router } from "https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts";

    const router = new Router();

    router.get('/', function ({ response }) {

    });

    router.post('/savedata', async function ({ request, response }) {

    });
```

Note that there is a detail above: The functions receive a **context object** as standard parameter (e.g. `router.get('/', function (context) { ... }`) so an alternative could be using the *destructuring assignment* (e.g.`router.get('/', ({ request, response, next})`).

Source: [OAK Documentation](https://github.com/oakserver/oak)

Answer (score 0):

I personally liked the annotation based Alosaur framework having annotations like @Controller which also supports dependency injection.

https://github.com/shantanum91/DenoRentApp

Answer (score 0):

I have created a boilerplate based on Oak. It could be helpful for those who are beginning with deno:

Deno REST:
https://github.com/vicky-gonsalves/deno_rest